# How to extend a button touch area in HTML5 for iPad?

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, safari

How do I extend the touch area around a div which has a bound touchstart event attached?

My code:

```
$('#div_button').bind('touchstart', function(e)
{
    // button action
});
```

I want the area around the button to trigger the touchstart for that button, because otherwise you have to tap your finger exactly on the button or the touchstart event wont be triggered.

The question is answered here for native iOS apps, but I want to do the same thing in an HTML5 Safari App for iPad.

[How to extend a button touch area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123227/how-to-extend-a-button-touch-area)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without the full code or an example.

How about adding a lot of `padding` to the `div`?

Depending on how `#div_button` is coded, this could allow for a much larger clickable area.